# Error passing large text with special characters in a variable to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, bash

I have an script that connects with SSH to a remote Host, and executes another script there which inserts data into a local MySQL database. I pass all the variables that need to be inserted within the SSH. All works fine excepts for the $textBody variable.I think the problem is that there ara a lot of text in this variable (included special characters that may be causing the error).

```
ssh -p 22 $user@$IP_ADDRESS "$SCRIPTMYSQL \"$taulaName\" \"$valueType\" \"$valueTitle\" \"$textBODY\" exit"
```

This is the error I get:

```
jailshell: -u: command not found
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\S'.
```

If I pass another variable different than $textBODY in his place, no error occurs.

Comment: What is `jailshell`? is that your login shell on that machine? What is the contents of your variables? Do any of them contain double quotes?

Comment: Jailshell i think is because I'm in a shared host, and they run jails. Don't worry about that.
And yes, I'm passing double quotes inside the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm passing double quotes inside the variable.

If `$textBODY` doesn't contain single quotes `'`, you can use them:

```
ssh -p 22 $user@$IP_ADDRESS "$SCRIPTMYSQL \"$taulaName\" \"$valueType\" \"$valueTitle\" '$textBODY' exit"
```

(that also applies to the other variables, of course).